# converting git submodules to regular directories

Tags: git, vim, git-submodules, vim-plugin

I would like to push some submodules (like vim bundles loaded through Vundle) as normal directories to my GitHub, since I am having difficulty getting the submodules one by one to my other machine. It will be much easier if I can push all bundles like normal directories

```
git add vim-workshop/bundle/Vundle.vim/*
```

I am getting following error when I run the above

```
fatal: Pathspec 'vim-workshop/bundle/Vundle.vim/autoload' is in submodule 'vim-workshop/bundle/Vundle.vim'
```

Is there an easy way to convert all submodules to normal directories. I tried removing .git in the submodule folder, that did not help

Comment: I think it's a combination of things... i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162000 (that's how to remove submodules). But you would do something similar, like git submodule deinit, then remove the .git file in the submodule directory, and manually edit the .gitmodules file. Just don't do the part where you delete the submodule directories.

Comment: no deinit command is failing

Comment: Do you mind to remove every git folder in the submodules and add the submodules again in the future? I can provide you a solution.

Comment: deinit is falling? What Git version are you using?

Comment: And can you provide the error message when `deinit` fails?